# Conexão Android com MySQL - Erro com metodo POST

Tags: php, java, android, mysql

Boa noite!
Eu estou desenvolvendo uma interface simples no Android Studio para login e cadastro de usuários. Segui os passos de um tutorial no youtube e quase tudo funciona perfeitamente, só estou com problema ao tentar me logar.

Código do botao Login:

```
 mBtnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){

                String login = mEdtLogin.getText().toString();
                String senha = mEdtPass.getText().toString();

                if(login.isEmpty() || senha.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login e senha devem ser preenchidos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    url = "meusite.com/login.php"; // Onde me refiro ao arquivo de conexão por PHP!
                    parametro = "login="+ login +"&senha="+ senha; //Este trecho eu tenho duvida se está correto pois estou utilizando o metodo POST no PHP e o formato deste parâmetro parece estranho. 
                    new SolicitaDados().execute(url);


                }



            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhuma conexão detectada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }





        }
    });
```

Código da classe que supostamente busca os dados de conexão:

```
private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{ //LINHA 83 DO ERRO 


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
            return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametro);
        } catch (Exception erro){
            return "Impossível se conectar a pagina";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado){ 


        if(resultado.contains("login_ok")){ // LINHA 99 DO ERRO - AQUI É ONDE OCORRE O ERRO, ISTO SEMPRE RETORNA NULL, JÁ DEBUGUEI O APP PAUSANDO AQUI
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainLoginActivity.this, Perfil.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuário ou senha incorretos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Código para classe Conexão no android:

```
 public static String postDados(String urlUsuario, String parametrosUsuario){
        URL url;
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

        try{
            url = new URL(urlUsuario);
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Lenght", "" + Integer.toString(parametrosUsuario.getBytes().length));

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "pt-BR");

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parametrosUsuario);
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        dataOutputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String linha;
            StringBuilder resposta = new StringBuilder();

            while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ){
                resposta.append(linha);
                resposta.append('\r');
            }

            bufferedReader.close();

            return resposta.toString();

        } catch (Exception erro){
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }


    }
```

Os código PHP estão funcionais pois já testei manualmente (trocando os metodos POST por GET e forçando o input), por isso acredito que o erro esteja no retorno do android.

O erro é o seguinte:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at project.waifu.com.waifuproject.MainLoginActivity$SolicitaDados.onPostExecute(MainLoginActivity.java:99)
    at project.waifu.com.waifuproject.MainLoginActivity$SolicitaDados.onPostExecute(MainLoginActivity.java:83)
```

A partir dai o App para de funcionar! Eu já procurei em todo lugar da internet mas nada resolveu isso!

Obs.: Se precisarem dos arquivos php me avisem!!

EDIT:
O erro estava no arquivo Conexão, eu estava retornando null dentro do um catch e por isso o app parava de funcionar!

```
catch (Exception erro){
        return null; //Alterei para uma mensagem de erro e tudo deu certo!
```

Comment: Adicionar `return null;` em um `try...catch` e não tratar o erro, é um erro muito grande. Verifique qual o erro está ocorrendo no método `postDados`. Para isso, adicione `error.printStackTrace();` antes de `return null;`.

Comment: Realmente, eu fiz o que você disse e alterei o retorno para uma mensagem de erro e o problema foi resolvido!!! Muito obrigado, eu nunca ia pensar que era ai o erro.

Comment: Alguém está acompanhando Duds tecnologia kkkkk

Comment: Aheaheauh temos um xeroque rolmes aqui